# JWT Brute force attack possible?

Tags: security, jwt

I was wondering if you had a JWT and did an offline brute force attack on it to get the servers secret key, if you could then sign valid JWTs?

The only reason I think this wouldn’t work is that once the server signs a JWT, it stores it somewhere locally. So even if the server verifies the signature, it won’t authenticate you as it has no local record of that token.

Is this true that the token is stored locally as well as in the client side?

Comment: In theory, yes, you could brute-force it, but not enough computing power exists to make this practical. Assuming you use the default settings. It's possible that later in our life time the computer power exists, so there's no guarantee that a JWT generated now can't be cracked 50 years from now.

Answer (score 2):

Some token providers do rotate (change) their private signing key on a regular basis. Second, access tokens usually have a short lifetime, like minutes, to days. So it would be pretty hard to crack in that timeframe.

You as a user only get access to the signature and the public key, with just the public key, is practically impossible to use brute-force to get the private key.

Also, for JWT's there are different signing algorithms (RSA, ECDSA..) and the ECDSA is stronger than RSA.